# Chebyshev's theorem on the distribution of primes

Tags: reference-request, analytic-number-theory

I a lecture V. Arnold says that Chebyshev had proved that the limit
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\pi(n)}{n/\mathrm{log}(n)}$$
 if exists is equal to one.

Where I can find the proof? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can find the result with discussion and references in my paper
[A remark on an inequality for the prime counting function](http://homepage.univie.ac.at/dietrich.burde/papers/burde_23_cheby_error.pdf).